# Groovy findIndexValues return List<Long>

Tags: collections, types, groovy

I must be going crazy but why is Groovy findIndexValues returning `List<long>`? Can I get the indices in Integer?

```
foo = ['a','b','d','e', 'e','e']
indices  = foo.findIndexValues { it == 'e'}
indices.each { println foo[it] }
```

The above will crash because foo collection cannot handle a long as a accessing index. Am I not using the language as it should be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's how that method works.  It traverses the collection with an iterator and keeps track of the matching indexes as longs.  In theory, it supports collections larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, although I'm doubtful this is useful in practice.

You can work around it with:

```
indices.each { println foo[it as int] }
```

Comment: I feel like that was a bad implementation decision. Especially when the documentation doesn't state so. I guess I just have to live with it.

Comment: findIndexValues works on an iterable,  so could have more elements than a list

Answer (score 2):

Rather than doing the conversion every time you use indices, just convert it all up front in the initial assignment instead.

```
foo = ['a','b','d','e', 'e','e']
indices  = foo.findIndexValues { it == 'e'}.collect { it as Integer }
indices.each { println foo[it] }
```